# Golang: statically finding all strings in code

Tags: go

I would like to parse a package and output all of the strings in the code. The specific use case is to collect sql strings and run them through a sql parser, but that's a separate issue.

Is the best way to do this to just parse this line by line? Or is it possible to regex this or something? I imagine that some cases might be nontrivial, such as multiline strings:

```
str := "This is
the full
string"

// want > This is the full string
```

Comment: Consider using the built-in language parser: https://pkg.go.dev/go/parser. If it's something you need to run whenever a file changes then creating a generator for 'go generate' (https://go.dev/blog/generate) is probably worth while.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [go/scanner](https://godoc.org/go/scanner) package to scan for strings in Go source code:

```
src, err := os.ReadFile(fname)
if err != nil {
    /// handle error
}

// Create *token.File to scan.
fset := token.NewFileSet()
file := fset.AddFile(fname, fset.Base(), len(src))

var s scanner.Scanner
s.Init(file, src, nil, 0)

for {
    pos, tok, lit := s.Scan()
    if tok == token.EOF {
        break
    }
    if tok == token.STRING {
        s, _ := strconv.Unquote(lit)
        fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", fset.Position(pos), s)
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/849QsbqVhho